# R shiny : link between sliderinput with hours, reactive and a plot

Tags: r, shiny

I don't succeed to have a link between a sliderInput with hours and a reactive in order to change the hour range in my plot...
the type of the hours column is hms in my script,
can somebody help me ? thanks a lot :slight_smile:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyTime)
library(lubridate) #variable temps

route_fond_degre <- c(1:10)
vitesse_fond_noeuds <- c(2:11)
heure <- c("01:05:30","01:05:31","01:05:32","01:05:33","01:05:34","01:05:35","01:05:36",
                    "01:05:37","01:05:38","01:05:39")
df_test <- data.frame(heure,  route_fond_degre, vitesse_fond_noeuds)


ui <- fluidPage(

             sliderInput(inputId = "periode",
                         label = "Période",
                         min = as.POSIXct("10:00:00",format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                         max = as.POSIXct("23:00:00",format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                         value = c(as.POSIXct("10:00:00",format = "%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("23:59:59",format = "%H:%M:%S")),
                         timeFormat = "%H:%M:%S"),
             #le slider s'affiche bien mais pas de lien avec le plot

             plotOutput("graph1")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

    date_filtre <- reactive({

      mini <- as.POSIXct(input$periode[1])
      maxi <- as.POSIXct(input$periode[2])

      #df_test <- df_test %>% filter(heure > hms("10:00:00")) # this works without sliderinput

      data_sel <- df_test %>% filter(heure > mini & heure < maxi)
      return(data_sel)
    })

    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

      g <- ggplot(date_filtre(), aes_string(x="heure", y = "route_fond_degre"))+
        geom_point()
      g

    })


}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `df_test$heure` to `POSIXct` type as well.

```
df_test$heure <- as.POSIXct(df_test$heure, format = '%T')
```